# Find the largest drop in attendance between yesterday and today SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to write a SQL query to find the grade with the largest drop in attendance between yesterday and today.

We have the following tables:

attendance: date | student_id | attendance

where attendance is either 'present' or 'absent'

and

students : student_id | grade

I tried

```
SELECT grade, COUNT(a.student_id) as 'present',
CASE 
  WHEN date = (SELECT MAX(date) FROM attendance_events) THEN 'today'
  ELSE 'yesterday'
END AS 'day'
FROM attendance a 
JOIN students s
ON a.student_id = s.student_id
WHERE attendance = 'present'
GROUP BY 1,3;
```

But obviously this only works if the only 2 days in the table are today and yesterday, and doesn't actually say which grade level had the largest drop in attendance, I would have to personally see which grade had the largest drop to answer the question.

Comment: How many grades are there in the table?  I assume this doesn't change...

Comment: There's no grade_level here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using window functions (available in MySQL 8.0), it is pretty straight-forward to find the class with the largest drop in attendance:

```
SELECT date, grade, today, yesterday, today - yesterday diff
FROM 
    (SELECT a.date, s.grade, COUNT(a.attendance) today, 
            LAG(COUNT(a.attendance), 1) OVER (PARTITION BY grade ORDER BY date) yesterday
     FROM attendance a JOIN students s ON a.student_id = s.student_id     
     WHERE a.attendance = 'present' 
       AND a.date >= DATE_SUB(DATE(NOW()), INTERVAL 1 DAY)    
     GROUP BY a.date, s.grade) last_days 
WHERE date = date(now()) 
ORDER BY diff LIMIT 1;
```

Explanation:  The subquery will compute the attendance for each grade for the last two days.  In addition, it uses the LAG window function to include the attendance of the same grade for the preceding day (partitions by grade and orders by date).

The outer query will select the rows for the current date and compute the difference between today's and yesterday's attendance.  To find the grade with the largest drop, we order by the computed difference and use LIMIT 1 to only return the row with the largest drop (or smallest increase if there is no drop for any class).

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you. I had previously commented why we needed to select the rows with the current date on the outer query but I get it now. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This solution supports grades 1 - 4.  I'll post the example query, then try to take it a apart a bit to help provide some insight into what's happening.

```
select
  absentY1 - absentT1 Grade1Reduction,
  absentY2 - absentT2 Grade2Reduction,
  absentY3 - absentT3 Grade3Reduction,
  absentY4 - absentT4 Grade4Reduction from (
  select
    sum(case when (date = date_format(date_sub(now(), interval 1 day), '%Y-%m-%d') and grade = 1) then absent else 0 end) absentY1,
    sum(case when (date = date_format(date_sub(now(), interval 1 day), '%Y-%m-%d') and grade = 2) then absent else 0 end) absentY2,
    sum(case when (date = date_format(date_sub(now(), interval 1 day), '%Y-%m-%d') and grade = 3) then absent else 0 end) absentY3,
    sum(case when (date = date_format(date_sub(now(), interval 1 day), '%Y-%m-%d') and grade = 4) then absent else 0 end) absentY4,
    sum(case when (date = date_format(now(), '%Y-%m-%d') and grade = 1) then absent else 0 end) absentT1,
    sum(case when (date = date_format(now(), '%Y-%m-%d') and grade = 2) then absent else 0 end) absentT2,
    sum(case when (date = date_format(now(), '%Y-%m-%d') and grade = 3) then absent else 0 end) absentT3,
    sum(case when (date = date_format(now(), '%Y-%m-%d') and grade = 4) then absent else 0 end) absentT4
  from (
    select a.date, s.grade, count(a.attendance) absent
    from attendance a left join students s on a.student_id = s.student_id
    where a.attendance = 'absent'
    group by a.date, s.grade
  ) as q
) as q2;
```

Okay, so it starts with this:

```
    select a.date, s.grade, count(a.attendance) absent
    from attendance a left join students s on a.student_id = s.student_id
    where a.attendance = 'absent'
    group by a.date, s.grade
```

That provides you data that counts the attendance and groups it by date and grade.  You will want to further limit this to today and yesterday...probably, or your query will end up taking forever as time goes on.  Just add `where date = date_format(date_sub(now(), interval 1 day), '%Y-%m-%d') or date = date_format(now(), '%Y-%m-%d')`. So at this point the output looks like this:

[image: sub sub query data grid]

but as you see, there isn't enough there to do the math.  That's why you have to know in advance how many grades there are.  So that then becomes the subquery to produce the somewhat laborious `absentY1` through `absentT4`.  I'll explain my shorthand.

I'm using *Y* to represent "Yesterday" and then the integer after it to represent the grade...so "Y1" is "yesterday, 1st grade".  "Y2" is "yesterday, 2nd grade" and so on and so forth.  Likewise, the "T" represents "Today".  Okay, so now the output is maturing (it has data for every day and grade):

[image: sub query]

Okay, finally, we can now do some simple math and come up with who has the greatest reduction in absences.  Note, that in the data i constructed, the 3rd grade has *more* absences, so the number is negative.  In this case, all other grades tie for greatest reduction...I suppose.

[image]

Here is the data I used, fwiw:

```
create table attendance (
  date date,
  student_id int unsigned,
  attendance varchar(7)
);

create table students (
  student_id int unsigned,
  grade int unsigned
);

insert into students values (100, 1), (101, 1), (102, 1), (201, 2), (202, 2), (203, 2), (301, 3), (302, 3), (303, 3), (401, 4);

insert into attendance values ('2019-11-10', 100, 'present'), ('2019-11-10', 101, 'present'), ('2019-11-10', 102, 'present'), ('2019-11-10', 201, 'present'), ('2019-11-10', 202, 'present'), ('2019-11-10', 203, 'present'), ('2019-11-10', 301, 'present'), ('2019-11-10', 302, 'present'), ('2019-11-10', 303, 'present'), ('2019-11-10', 401, 'present'), ('2019-11-11', 100, 'absent'), ('2019-11-11', 101, 'present'), ('2019-11-11', 102, 'present'), ('2019-11-11', 201, 'present'), ('2019-11-11', 202, 'present'), ('2019-11-11', 203, 'present'), ('2019-11-11', 301, 'absent'), ('2019-11-11', 302, 'absent'), ('2019-11-11', 303, 'present'), ('2019-11-11', 401, 'present');
```

Comment: Thank you! This is a very thorough and thoughtful explanation. I was wondering if maybe there was a way to get around manually writing subqueries for every grade but I guess this would be the best way to do it if we didn't have too many grades. Thanks again!

Comment: Programmatic logic is really necessary to make this elegant.  Procedural SQL or C++ or PHP or _something else_ to handle the individual levels of grade.  If you do that, you only need the "it starts with this" query...then the "program" does the interpolation and can handle a variable number of grades.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution that doesn't use Window functions:

```
SELECT grade FROM
    ( 
     SELECT 
         s.grade_level AS grade, 
         SUM(CASE WHEN ae.date = curdate() AND ae.attendance = 
                  'present' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS att_today,

         SUM(CASE WHEN ae.date = adddate(curdate(), INTERVAL -1 DAY) AND ae.attendance = 
                  'present' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS att_yesterday

     FROM attendance_events AS ae
     JOIN all_students AS s
     ON ae.student_id = s.student_id
     GROUP BY s.grade_level) AS subq

ORDER BY (att_yesterday - att_today) DESC
LIMIT 1;
```